# How to apply date format in pyspark SQL

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

we get below data from below pyspark sql query

[image]

Script::

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.master('yarn').appName('myAppName').getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.parquet('gs://data/test')
df.createOrReplaceTempView("people")

df2=spark.sql("""select id,concat(year(dates) ,'_',month(dates)) as date,
    count(1) count
    from people
group by id, month(dates),year(dates)
```

And expected output is

[image]

like 2019_jan, 2019_feb, 2019_oct,.... 2019_Dec
Kindly help me about date format syntax in pyspark sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like below

```
spark.sql("select date_format(current_date(),'MMM') as month from data")
```

Your complete query should be like this

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df2=spark.sql("""select id,concat(year(dates) ,'_',date_format(dates,'MMM')) as date,
    count(1) count from people group by id, date_format(dates,'MMM'),year(dates)
```